# Serializing an object in Symfony

Tags: api, symfony, serialization

Within my Review entity:

```
/**
 * @Groups({"books"})
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Book\MainBundle\Entity\Book", inversedBy="reviews")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bookID", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $bookID;
```

And within my Controller, I have:

```
public function getReviewsAction()
{
    $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $reviews = $em->getRepository('BookMainBundle:Review')->findAll();
    $serializer->serialize($reviews, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('Default', 'books')));
    return $this->handleView($this->view($reviews));
}
```

However serialization isn't working at all, does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: read this article, http://thomas.jarrand.fr/blog/serialization/

Comment: what do you mean by "isn't working at all"? What do you retrieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the following:

```
$serializer->serialize($reviews, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('Default', 'books')));
```

This will serialize the reviews but not assign it to anything.

You probably want to do something like:

```
$serializedReviews = $serializer->serialize($reviews, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('Default', 'books')));
return $this->handleView($this->view($serializedReviews));
```